# Java: Very Slow Communication with sockets when on LAN

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ipc

I have a  class in Java that needs to run on a separate machine due to RAM requirements. The class requires ~5GB or RAM. Thus, I have developed a solution that uses sockets in order to allow the machines to communicate.
For simplicity lets assume that the heavy class under a socket server wrapper is the Service Class. The client class that connects to the socket server lets assume is the Client Class.

When the Socket Server runs locally everything is perfect. The server runs as a standalone app and there is no need to reload the ~5GB every time I start my experiments. However, I realized that when the Service Class runs on a different machine over LAN the performance is terribly slow. The issue is not the transfer rate since when monitoring it I see ~50K/s max transfer rate.

On the client class that connects to the Server uses Buffering using `BufferedInput`/`Output` stream.

Let me provide the **Server Thread:**

```
public void run() {
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            ServerTuple tuple;
            double i=0;
            while ((tuple = (ServerTuple) ois.readObject()) != null) {
                double[] vector;
                String action=tuple.action;
                String content=tuple.content;
                if(action.equals("wordVector"))
                {
                    vector=Word2Vec.getWordVector(tuple.content);
                }
                else if(action.equals("avgVector2"))
                {
                    content=content.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
                    vector=Word2Vec.getWordVector2(content.split(" "));
                }
                else
                    vector=null;
              tuple.setVector(vector);
              oos.writeObject(tuple);
              oos.flush();
            }
            //oos.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return;
        }


    }
```

And the **Client Procedure:**

```
public static void init(String host,int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        socket=new Socket(host,port);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    }

public static ServerTuple sendData(ServerTuple tuple) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
            if(socket==null)
            {
                init();
            }
            oos.writeObject(tuple);
            oos.flush();
            ServerTuple returnTuple;
            while ((returnTuple = (ServerTuple) ois.readObject()) != null) {
                if(returnTuple.vector==null)
                    return null;
              return returnTuple;
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the client do exactly? Why is the client using buffered streams, but not the server? 50KB/sec is terribly slow: why do you think that rate is not a problem? And why does the server needs so much RAM in the first place? What does it do?

Comment: The Server calculates word embeddings. The model that needs to be loaded to the RAM is ~2GB compressed but when loaded it takes 5-7GB of RAM. I think that speed is not the issue because my network speed is 150Mb/s so this is not the bottleneck.